# How to use Youtube Class on View

Tags: php, laravel, youtube, laravel-5.5

I am using [Youtube](https://github.com/alaouy/Youtube) package

I added this on **app.php**

```
Alaouy\Youtube\YoutubeServiceProvider::class,
```

&

```
'Youtube' => Alaouy\Youtube\Facades\Youtube::class,
```

now i m trying in view like this

```
{{ Youtube::getVideoInfo('rie-hPVJ7Sw') }}
```

but getting error

> "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>    (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\guru\resources\views\admin\video\index.blade.php)"

how can I fix this?

i Tried

```
@foreach($videos as $video)
  {{ var_dump(Youtube::getVideoInfo($video->videoid)) }}
@endforeach
```

its showing me everything

Here is Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Try this: `{ \Youtube::getVideoInfo('rie-hPVJ7Sw') }}` Let me know if it works!

Comment: its working when i type this {{ var_dump(Youtube::getVideoInfo($video->videoid)) }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs,

> // Return an STD PHP object
>   $video = Youtube::getVideoInfo('rie-hPVJ7Sw');

so you could do,

```
{{ var_dump(Youtube::getVideoInfo('rie-hPVJ7Sw')) }}
```

to print out the object or assign it to a variable and access the respective object properties

**EDIT**

To show only the embed html you could use the following code

```
@foreach($videos as $video)
  {!! Youtube::getVideoInfo($video->videoid)->player->embedHtml !!}
@endforeach
```

Comment: but how to render video

Comment: What's the output of `{{ var_dump(Youtube::getVideoInfo('rie-hPVJ7Sw')) }}` ?

Comment: everything which i need video id title link embed

Comment: Then use an `iframe` to render the video using the embed code

Comment: ?? i think something wrong here is my code in view
 @foreach($videos as $video)
             {{ var_dump(Youtube::getVideoInfo($video->videoid)) }}
             @endforeach

Comment: @SidHeart Please update your question with relevant details, as it is difficult to make out from the comments, what's the issue

Comment: i added screenshot please check

Comment: @SidHeart check the modified answer

Comment: again error "Undefined property: stdClass::$embedHTML (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\guru\resources\views\admin\video\index.blade.php)"

Comment: Why would you want to escape html?

Comment: i just got what i want thank you so much you save my days

Comment: So is the output delivered using `{{}}` or is it delivered using `{!!!!}` ?

Comment: when i use {{}} its show me full code example <iframe src="youtube-link" >
when i use {!!!!} its output complete video Thanks